# "星を投げ合う" in the context of the Internet

Tags: translation, meaning, song-lyrics, internet-slang

The link is down right now for non-Japanese users, but the song [Social Network(そーしゃるねっとわーく)](http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm25327660) has these lyrics in it:

> 好きな時に電源を入れて　誰かの文字列を覗き込む
>
> 星を投げ合うだけくらいが心地良い　僕のもうひとつの “部屋” 秘密の場所

It's pretty obvious what they're talking about for the most part, but "星を投げ合う" confuses me. I do know that this song was published back when "likes" on Twitter were represented by stars, so I was thinking maybe that has something to do with it.

Does anybody know if likes were ever referred to as "星," or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: What is your attempt? 'Throwing stars (likes) back and forth feels fine' (reciprocally liking each other's posts) seems to be the meaning here.

Comment: Yeah, it was something along those lines. "Just passing likes around feels pretty good." My question was more "can anyone verify that people refer(red) to likes as '星'?" since I've only seen "いいね" in that context. I'll edit the main post.

Comment: Lyrics: https://www24.atwiki.jp/utauuuta/pages/3519.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, back in the days favorites on twitter was referred to as 星.
 This blog post -- [「いいね」のサムズアップ感をTwitterに持ち込むということ - うらがみらいぶらり](http://wasasula.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/11/04/235918) -- writes up the author's sentiments on the change to :hearts:. It reads:

> だが少なくとも「ふぁぼ」と呼び、「ふぁぼれよ」ということばが通じ、星を投げ合うような文化圏は、やはり世界全体で見れば少数派には違いない。

"ふぁぼ-る" as a verb was also commonly used when the function was called favorites rather than likes, and formed a kind of culture.

「いいね」, you mentioned, is a newer term introduced when Twitter took our stars away and started calling them "like"s.

Comment: ShootingStar とか，ふぁぼ規制とか，華やかなりし一時代のことを思い出して少しノスタルジー